# Drupal 7 ability to use other databases in the web form module

Tags: webforms

We used webform-7.x-3.20 module in our web site.
But we want to connect and use a database different than drupal's default database.

Below you can find example DB setting.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (

  'database' => 'example_1',

  'username' => 'example_1',

  'password' => 'example_1',

  'host' => 'localhost',

  'port' => '',

  'driver' => 'mysql',

  'prefix' => 'example_',

);

$databases['default2']['default'] = array (

  'database' => 'example_2',

  'username' => 'example_2',

  'password' => 'example_2',

  'host' => 'localhost',

  'port' => '',

  'driver' => 'mysql',

  'prefix' => 'example_',

);
```

As a conlusion we want to use the second DB in webform modules. The rest will used the first DB that is default.

We could not be succesful in realizing this.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Elaborate your problem a bit more so others can provide you a meaningful answer. When you say that you use module "forms" do you mean [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform) or something else? Also explain in more details what are you trying to achieve, what is your setup and what have you tried already.

Comment: Additionally, if this is a feature request for Webform module, you should post in module's issue queue, not here.